# TypeError: datetime.datetime is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, datetime, time

I'm learning Python and aws.

What I want is to extract value from the JSON response. This code works for JSON response that doesn't contain date values, but in this case **response** contains **date** value.

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, datetime
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('lex-models')

response = client.get_utterances_view(
          botName='CreateServicesBot',
          botVersions=[
                     '$LATEST',
                      ],
          statusType='Missed'
          )

with open('/tmp/output.json', 'w') as data:
          json.dump(response,data)

with open('/tmp/output.json') as f:
          data = json.load(f)
ustr=data["utteranceString"]
print ustr
```

I'm getting this error:

> `TypeError: datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 7, 9, 44, 38, 146000, 
>       tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable`

Does someone know the solution?
thx

Comment: Next time please use the search function before posting.

Comment: Hello, that did not answer my questions i can't resolve it.

Comment: json.dumps(d, default=str)    will do the job. 'default' parameter helps to cast/convert unserializable objects to the given type/function

Answer (score 6):

As the error suggests you are trying to dump into json a `datetime.datetime` object and this is not possible.

What you can do, is to convert those objects into a string and then dump it. Say that the field which contains a `datetime.datetime` is called `date` then you need to do the following before exporting to the `json` file

```
response[date] = response[date].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score -4):

i did what you asked

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, datetime
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('lex-models')

response = client.get_utterances_view(
    botName='CreateServicesBot',
    botVersions=[
        '$LATEST',
    ],
    statusType='Missed'
)
response[lastUtteredDate] = response[lastUtteredDate].strftime("%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S")
response[firstUtteredDate] = response[firstUtteredDate].strftime("%Y-%m-%d 
%H:%M:%S")


with open('/tmp/output.json', 'w') as data:
    json.dump(response,data)


with open('/tmp/output.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
ustr=data["utteranceString"]
print ustr
```

and i got this error

> NameError: name 'lastUtteredDate' is not defined

when i print **response** i got this (the first block)

> {u'utterances': [{u'utterances': [{u'count': 49, u'utteranceString': u'hello', >u'**lastUtteredDate**': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 7, 9, 44, 38, 146000, >tzinfo=tzlocal()), u'distinctUsers': 42, u'**firstUtteredDate**': > > >datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 31, 8, 52, 34, 907000, tzinfo=tzlocal())},

Comment: Please don't use answers to post comments.

Comment: The comment area does not support too many characters

Comment: @Beastn this should have been posted as an update to the question. Not posted as an answer.

Comment: just replace `lastUtteredDate` with `'lastUtteredDate'`